# Is there a way to change the background color of a slide in OpenOffice.org Impress using hexadecimal values?

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-impress

So far I've only found a way to change the background color by right-clicking the slide and going to **Slide** > **Page Setup** > **Background** > **Color**, but it only shows a fixed selection of colors, like this:

[image]

I was wondering if it was possible to actually specify the color using the hexadecimal notation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sort of.  You need to add a color to the list.  Select **Format -> Area**, then seldect the **Color** tab.  You can enter color as RGB (0 to 255) or CMYK.

[image: OO color picker]

It's pretty easy to convert the 0 - 255 decimal values to hex.